# How to programatically assign random colors to objects in 3ds max?

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

How to programatically assign random colors to objects in 3ds max?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That works well if you just want to assign a random wire color. Here is some code for creating a standard material with a random diffuse color.

```
for o in $* do 
( 
  m = standard
  m.diffuse = random white black 
  o.material = m
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I didn't know how to do it!

Answer (score 3):

This is what I found online as a solution:

```
for o in $* do
(
o.wirecolor = random white black
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Various ways:

For wirecolor changes (i.e.-objects with no scene material on them) you can do,

(for mesh objects only)

```
for o in geometry do
(
     o.wirecolor = random black white
)
```

for all scene objects you can do

```
for o in objects do
(
     o.wirecolor = random black white
)
```

for all objects that are selected you can do

```
for o in selection do
(
     o.wirecolor = random black
)
```

for only a single object, you can do

```
selection[1].wirecolor = random black white
```

Answer (score 0):

for object that match a criteria use the where clause

```
for o in objects where <someproperty> == <somevalue> do o.wirecolor = random black white
```

so like..

```
for o in objects where classof o == Sphere and o.radius > 10.0 do o.wirecolor = random black white
```

or filter by the objects name then create and apply a standard material:

```
for o in objects where matchpattern o.name pattern:"Sphere*" do o.material = (standard diffuse:(random white black))
```